# Always have audio out from usb soundcard and stream over IP on a multi-user desktop system

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, soundcard, streaming

First off, sorry if 'parts' of this have been answered before, I'm just struggling to work out a suitably non-complex way of linking everything.

I want to build a new system using Ubuntu 20.04LTS instead of Windows 10. But before I make that plunge I need to work out how to do this question.

I have a setup where I need a 'normally' odd set of requirements.

I would need all system audio to play via an external usb soundcard (which has a s/pdif toslink adapter which is used to connect to external audio gear) and also  be streamed via IP to another LAN machine so it too can play the audio via its speakers (think Auditorium and foyer type scenario where the machine in the foyer wants to be playing the pre-event music that is also playing in the Auditorium but closely in-sync- as good as can be given IP latencies - so moving from one zone to another is nicely linked for a nice experience)...

I need this to occur across all users (ie a privileged admin type account, 1 lesser privileged account and possibly one completey non-privilaged account) on a multi-user desktop environment, right from bootup with no additional post login steps to enable.

I've been looking at pulseaudio and or JACK and running in a deamon mode with systemd but even Pulseaudio's documentation says thats a really bad idea, so I'm kinda at a loss as to the best way to do it...

The audio out the system will 99.999% be 2.0 stereo, but might be 5.1 However, when playing 5.1 the 2nd machines output would be expected to be turned off, so all it needs to do is not break down and blow up!

I know I can do this in windows 10 with VB Audio's Voicemeeter and VBAN network audio protocol (was looking at an excellent linux implementation of the VBAN transmitter so that might be useful), so if I can do it with Ubuntu I would install that instead!

Does that make any sense and sorry for a long worded novella!

Any ideas and help understanding how I would link different things together would be genuinely helpful!!!

I appreciate some of these may have been individually answered as individual units, but I don't know how you would link them, or if its even possible!!!

Comment: It's best if you install Ubuntu, or use Ubuntu in a live session to try to figure this out on your own first.  If and when you encounter actual problems, you can ask about them here.  It's hard to answer hypothetical questions because there are no details to work with.

Comment: @Nmath yh, I appreciate the advice and was something I was going to do (next few days) I just wasn't even sure it was possible.... its the multi-user but that I think complicates it and i suppose I was really asking if this IS a use case for running PuseAudio in daemon mode irrespective of the risks?